# How to acquire token for delegated permissions (microsoft graph)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I have a registered app in AAD where I have provided `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permissions with **admin consent**. Until now I was working only with Application permissions.

I authenticated like this:

```
public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var clientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
        .WithTenantId(TenantId)
        .Build();

        var result = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(this.AppScopes).ExecuteAsync();
    
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", result.CreateAuthorizationHeader());
}
```

Afterwards I just called the needed endpoints. Now my goal is to delete AAD device during workflow and the application runs in the background without any user interaction. Is it possible to authorize somehow without any user interaction and acquire the token for the application to work with?

Comment: The user has to sign in at some point, but after that you can [get the token from the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Crowcoder, unfortunately my app is running without any user interaction and I would like the service (registered app) to get the bearer token to delete AAD device completely without any interaction.

Comment: If you want to use delegated permissions you have to have a logged in user.

Comment: @Crowcoder, sorry to take a bit more of your time. To fully understand. A web app can run in the background without any problem while it's using Application permissions, correct? But if I would like to interact with calls that uses Delegated permissions, there is no other way around, but the user will be prompted to log in, that the app could act on its behalf?

Comment: A web app isn't well suited for running without user interaction. I know background tasks have gotten better since .NET Core but if this is behaving like a service, maybe it should be a proper service. And it sounds like you want to use application permissions instead of delegated after all. Why the change?

Comment: To elaborate a bit more on the situation, I have a web app that according to user selection inputs a record to DB. Scheduled task runs a desktop app where it takes records from the database and works with Graph API, so far application permissions where sufficient. Now a use case to delete AAD device came up and it needs delegated permissions. That is why I can not provide a user interaction. I searched in MS documentation if that can be avoided, but I gave up and came here to ask. I was a bit unclear in the beginning comments, sorry. @Crowcoder

Comment: Did you figure out how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Graph exposes two kinds of permissions: application and delegated. For apps that run with a signed-in user, you request delegated permissions in the scope parameter. These permissions delegate the privileges of the signed-in user to your app, allowing it to act as the signed-in user when making calls to Microsoft Graph. These require user activity and tokens will have both applications as well as user claims.

You cannot use delegated scenarios without user interaction.
At present delete device scenario only supports delegated permissions. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for your reference.
My guess is because deleting a device is considered more complex operation (as opposed to read).

Being said that, if you wish to have application permissions supported for this, please raise a [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask explaining your scenario so it could be considered for future implementations.

Thanks.